# Rails link_to index with variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this index action in my collections_controller

```
def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @collections = @user.collections(:status).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

I have these two links on my home page

```
<%= user_collections_path(@user, :status => "Got") %>">collection</a>
<%= user_collections_path(@user, :status => "Want") %>">wantlist</a>
```

The idea is they will link to this index page

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name ) %>
<h1><% if current_user?(@user) %>Your<% else %>
    <%= @user.name %>'s<% end %> collection</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <%= render @collections %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

which in turn loads this partial

```
<li>
  <%= image_tag collection.photo.url(:icon), :retina => true %>

  <%= link_to collection.miniature.name, collection %>
  <%= collection.progress %>
</li>
```

Polulating it with either the user collections marked as "Got" or the user collections marked as "Want" depending on which link is clicked.

Currently the index is loading ALL of a user's collections. Albeit at paths which look right to me (e.g. /users/1/collections?status=Got)

I assume the fault is with this line in the controller  `@collections = @user.collections(:status).paginate(page: params[:page])`

Instead of (:status) do I need something like `@user.collections.where(:status = "?")` perhaps?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking a question?
Or just confirming your answer
Yes, index action should be like

@collections = @user.collections.where(status: params[:status]).paginate(page: params[:page])

Comment: Was absolutely asking a question because though I WAS on the right track I couldn't get it quite right. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, index action should be like

```
@user.collections.where(status: params[:status]).paginate(page: params[:page])
```